# POSIX (MySQL RLIKE) Regex to match A|B|C but eliminate D|E|F

Tags: mysql, regex, posix, repeat

I had a completely working version on my Windows XAMPP testbed (in PHP)

```
SELECT... ...WHERE itemTitle RLIKE '(?=.*A)+(?=.*B)+(?=.*C)+^((?!D|E|F).)*$'
```

that stopped working when I moved the site to a real server with the error "repetition operator operand invalid".

Research says that the UNIX based server only supports a more basic RegEx that does NOT allow look-aheads or behinds..?

Six hours+ of searching and testing on my local site and the real server lead to no solution on my own.

To clarify, I need the (MySQL) to return records that have multiple matching strings (in a given column) but ELIMINATE the ones with a seconds set of matching strings... WITHOUT using any repetition operators!

```
BETTER EXPLANATION OF REQUIREMENTS:
Given two strings: "The quick brown fox" & "A slow red fox", a regex that tries these lists of substrings (in POSIX only, no lookarounds) where _all pluses must be there in any order, but can have _none of the minuses...
'+qui +th -red' matches first string, fails second
'+fox +o' matches both strings
'+fox -q' fails first string, matches second
'+ow -fo' fails both strings
(plus/minus for represent only)
```

Comment: What this `(?=.*A)+` supposed to mean? Please [edit] the question and provide examples of string that should and shouldn't match (as text!).

Comment: what does `select version();` show?

Comment: If `A`, `B`, etc stand for a longer pattern, you cannot translate it into a POSIX pattern.

Comment: Please provide some examples of strings that should match and some that should not.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your current Title, this should work fine, and be somewhat efficient:

```
WHERE itemTitle     RLIKE '[ABC]'
  AND itemTitle NOT RLIKE '[DEF]'
```

That assumes the tests are for single letters, no anchoring is needed, etc.

```
WHERE 'The quick brown fox' RLIKE 'qu.*ox'  -- succeeds

WHERE 'The quick brown fox' RLIKE 'ox.*qu'  -- fails

WHERE 'The quick brown fox' RLIKE '(quick|fast)'  -- succeeds

WHERE 'The quick brown fox' NOT RLIKE '(slow|dead)'  -- succeeds

WHERE 'The quick brown fox' RLIKE '(quick|fast)'  
  AND 'The quick brown fox' NOT RLIKE '(slow|dead)'
-- succeeds, but it takes two RLIKEs


'+qui +th -red' -->

    WHERE col REGEXP 'qui'
      AND col REGEXP 'th'
      AND NOT col REGEXP 'red'
```

That is, each string must be checked separately.  `-` turns into `NOT`.  I do not think it is possible to combine those 3 tests into a single regexp.

However, you can combine all the minuses together:

```
'+blah -this -that' -->

    WHERE col REGEXP 'blah'
      AND col NOT REGEXP '(this|that)'
```

"all pluses must be there in any order" -- The "any order" prevents combining them into a single REGEXP.  (Or at least not in a single inteligable, efficient, regexp.)

Comment: Not testing for single letters, but parts of words; letters were placeholders in my example. Give the string "The quick brown fox", the following (simplified usage) would match: regex=qu ox the, but regex=the qu ox blah, would not, nor regex=the qu ox -brow... without lookarounds, posix only, must match when all substrings are present, but exclude where any of other substrings present.

Comment: @URi613 - I added some more examples.  If that is not enough, edit your Question with more examples of what you want or don't want.